# How to change email address for all users?

Tags: git

I successfully converted out svn to git. The problem is that we entered wrong emails for the commit authors. Is it possible to change the email address in git commit's author?

10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git filter-branch` is what you’re looking for. It’s not for the faint of heart, though, and will potentially change *all* commits of your repository which is a bad thing if you already published the repository.

```
git filter-branch --env-filter 'if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" == "old@email"]; then export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="new@email"; fi' -- --all
```

This should rewrite the history of all available refs (hence, `--all`), replacing all commit authors’ email addresses that match “old@email” with “new@email.”

Comment: Will this change the commit date or something else?

Comment: This will probably change `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` but not `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`.